# Syntax highlighting of coffeescript in Jade template with Sublime Text 2

Tags: coffeescript, sublimetext2, syntax-highlighting, pug

I am writing coffeescript code inside a jade template using Sublime Text 2. The coffeescript code inside :coffee(bare=true) tag lost track from syntax highlighting, it does not give any highlighting at all (all the code are in white color).

Here is a sample:

```
!!! 5
html
    head
        meta(charset="utf-8")
        title Sample
    body
    :coffee(bare=true)
        greet = (name) ->
            return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'
        console.log greet 'World'
```

I am using the packages, CoffeeScript (https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/CoffeeScript) and Jade (https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Jade) for syntax highlighting. They work nicely in separate files (.jade, .coffee), but not together. Can anyone help?

Comment: To make this work, coffeescript syntax support has to be added to the jade package.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Do you know which file(s) I should modify?